# cakephp: index site with all related habtm data

Tags: cakephp

Im trying since 3 days yout solution to get this to work, but i need help. mostly i made try&error. if someone can give me a solution, i could reverse-engineer it and understand cakephp better.

What i want is an index view like this (made a graphic):
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=fd8e93-1340110385.png

Door and Key has a habtm relation, and i want to list all doors which belong to 1 key

i have 3 tables:

doors(id, title,txt)
keys(id,number,description)
doors_keys(door_id,key_id)

here is my **key.php**

```
<?php

class Key extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array ('Door');
    public $displayField = 'description';
    // containable
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

**door.php**

```
<?php



class Door extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Door';
    public $belongsTo = array('Building');
    //public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Key');
    // validation array wird aufgemacht
    public $validate = array(
    // validation wird für das Datenbankfeld title definiert
        'title' => array(
        // Feld darf nicht leer sein
            'rule' => 'notEmpty' ,
            // Eintrag muss ausgewählt werden
            'required' => true
        ),
        // validation für das DB Feld building_id
        'building_id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty' ,
            'required' => true
        ),
    );
    // viele türen sind in einem Gebäude-> n:1->$belongsTo
    // in der tabelle doors muss ein fremdschluessel auf die andere datenbank angelegt sein


}
```

**keyscontroller.php** (NOT WORKING)

```
class KeysController extends AppController {


public function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
      'contain' => array(
        // we want to get the key
        'Door' => array(
       // the info i wanna know is in the field txt
          'fields' => array('txt')

        ),

          ),
        );
        $keys = $this->paginate('Key');
    debug($this->set(compact('keys')));
}
```

**index.ctp from keys**

```
<h2>Schluessel selbstgemacht</h2>

<table>
<!-- tr definiert eine Tabellenzeile -->
    <tr>
        <!-- th Überschriften in der Zeile -->
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>number</th>
    </tr>


<?php foreach($keys as $key): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key['Key']['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['Key']['description'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['Key']['number'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['Door']['txt'] ?></td>

        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Details', '/keys/view/' . $key['Key']['id']) ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('bearbeiten', '/keys/edit/' . $key['Key']['id']) ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('loeschen', '/keys/delete/' . $key['Key']['id']) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

i guess this is a basic question, but i cant find the solution. so i need a bit of help on this one. thanks

Comment: i dont know how to edit my post. so the above example is wrong, please ignore the following bacause it shows wrong:

door1----key1 ----key2 door2 ---key1 door3----key4

Comment: still need help. look underneath this post.

Comment: to edit your question, right above this comment section, you should see the tag you choose, cakephp. Right below that should be and edit link.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'recursive' => 1` to your Door->find() in order to get the data for the related Keys:

```
class KeysController extends AppController {
    public function index() {

    $doors = $this->Door->find(
        'recursive' => 1
    );
    $this->set('doors', $doors);

    // Look at the result
    debug($doors);
}
```

However, using `recursive` gets quite messy if your model relations are complex. Using [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) on your models is recommended instead.